# SBT: multi project leads to NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am writing a nsc plugin for scalac. The project consists of 3 different modules:

- **core** (classes used both in the plugin and user code)
- **plugin**
- **samples**

My build.sbt file is

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

lazy val sharedSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
  scalaVersion  := "2.12.1",
  organization  := "localhost",
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-unchecked")
)


lazy val usePluginSettings = Seq(
    scalacOptions ++= {
      val jar = (Keys.`package` in (plugin, Compile)).value
      val addPlugin = "-Xplugin:" + jar.getAbsolutePath
      val dummy = "-Jdummy=" + jar.lastModified
      Seq(addPlugin, dummy)
    }
  )


lazy val main = Project(
    id = "main",
    base = file("."),
    aggregate = Seq(plugin, core, samples)
  )

lazy val core = Project(
    id = "core",
    base = file("core")
  ) settings (
    sharedSettings: _*
  ) settings (
    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.17"
  )

lazy val plugin = Project(
    id   = "typestate",
    base = file("plugin")
  ) settings (
    sharedSettings: _*
  ) settings (
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
  ) dependsOn (core)

lazy val samples = Project(
    id   = "samples",
    base = file("samples")
  ) settings (
    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.17"
  ) settings (
    sharedSettings ++ usePluginSettings: _*
  ) dependsOn (core)
```

Now when I try to compile the module *samples* I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with a reference to a class in my *core* module. However when removing `usePluginSettings` the module can be compiled without any error.

As far as I know the problem is caused by the missing *core* artifacts in plugin's jar. I tried to add the sbt-assembly task to the build in order to get a fat-jar, but I didn't succeed.

Does anyone have a solution?